# How can I associate a set of variable length variables?

Tags: c, arrays, object, associations, struct

Suppose I've got a set of arrays and strings and constants:

```
const int a[]={0x01, 0x02};
const int b[]={2,0};
const int c=234;
const char* name="foo";
```

that together make up the object foo.

And there are many similar objects, such as

```
const int a[]={0x04, 0x02, 0x03};
const int b[]={2,0,1};
const int c=1234;
const char* name="arfle";
```

What is the best way to declare these objects in C? (specifically gcc, and I have no problem with gcc-only extensions, c99 etc..)

I'm hoping for something like

```
thing[0]={a={0x04, 0x02, 0x03}, b={2,0,1}, c=1234, name="arfle"};
thing[1]={a={0x01, 0x02}, b={2,0}, c=234, name="foo"};

printf("%s", thing.name);
```

But any neat method of solving the general problem will do.
I *can* put a maximum length on any of the arrays, although extra credit if I don't have to.
I have no problem at all with preprocessor trickery, and run-time initialization won't kill me, although I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a combination of all the answers so far, with a test loop.

This is what I'm actually going to use, I think. Thanks everybody for your help!

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct object_s
{
  int *a;
  size_t sizeof_a;
  int *b;
  size_t sizeof_b;
  int c;
  const char *name;
} object_t ;

#define DECLARE_OBJECT(a,b,c,d)   { (a), (sizeof(a)/(sizeof(int))),(b), sizeof(b)/(sizeof(int)), (c),(d)}

object_t thing[] = {
  DECLARE_OBJECT(((int[]){4,3,2}), ((int[]){ 2, 0, 1 }), 1234, "arfle"),
  DECLARE_OBJECT(((int[]){1,2})  , ((int[]){ 2, 0 })   ,  234, "foo")
};

int main(void) {
  int i,j;
  for(j=0; j<((sizeof(thing)/(sizeof(object_t)))); j++){
    printf("%s\n", thing[j].name);
    for(i=0; i<thing[j].sizeof_a; i++) printf("%d, ", thing[0].a[i] );
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<thing[j].sizeof_b; i++) printf("%d, ", thing[0].b[i] );
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n",thing[j].c);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a structure:

```
struct object
{
  int *a;
  int *b;
  int c;
  const char *name;
}

int arfle_a[] = { 4, 3, 2 };
int arfle_b[] = { 2, 0, 1 };
int foo_a[] = { 1, 2 };
int foo_b[] = { 2, 0 };
struct object thing[] = {
  { arfle_a, arfle_b, 1234, "arfle" },
  { foo_a, foo_b, 234, "foo" },
};

printf("%s\n", thing[1].name);
```

Note that this representation is pretty weak, it would be better (but more complicated) to represent the integer vectors with a size too, since now it's impossible to know how many numbers are in `a` or `b` at runtime.

**UPDATE**: I fixed the broken code, my apologies. That's what I get from posting untested code. :/

Comment: you cannot initialize your `struct` objects this way, the members are pointers not arrays.

Comment: That would be wonderful, but I can't seem to get it to compile.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden in C99 you could use compound literals as initializers in @unwind code: like `(int [3]) {4, 3, 2}` instead of `{4, 3, 2}`

Comment: @ouah: Thanks, I should have tested it myself. :|

Comment: Guys, thanks to you both, a combination of your answers looks like it might be the answer. I've posted such a combination below, but if either of you want to repost something like that I'll delete my self-answer and vote yours up. If anyone can macroize it so that I don't have to repeat the arrays that will be a full answer which I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a structure type to hold the different members.

As your arrays are of different sizes, use pointers and dynamically allocate the array objects.

```
struct bla {
    const int *a;
    const int *b;
    int c;
    const char *name;
};
```

if you don't want to construct you struct object by dynamically allocating the `a` and `b`  arrays, you can also initialize objects of `struct bla` type with C99 compound literals and C99 designated initializers.

```
struct bla a = {.a = (const int [3]) {4, 2, 3},
                .b = (const int [2]) {2, 0},
                .c = 42,
                .name = "arfle"};
```

You should also add struct members to store the number of elements of your array objects.

Comment: I'll probably need to put the lengths in somewhere as well, and what should my declarations look like?

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden yes, you will have to store the length (or always use a trailing null character to mark the end like for strings)

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of unwind's answer and ouah's comments:

Finding a good way of getting rid of the repeated arrays in the declarations would finish the job.

```
struct object
{
  int *a;
  int sizeof_a;
  int *b;
  int sizeof_b;
  int c;
  const char *name;
};

struct object thing[] = {
  { (int[]){ 4, 3, 2 }, sizeof((int[]){ 4, 3, 2 }), (int[]){ 2, 0, 1 }, sizeof((int[]){ 2, 0, 1 }), 1234, "arfle" },
  { (int[]){ 1, 2 }, sizeof((int[]){ 1,2 }), (int[]){ 2, 0 }, sizeof((int[]){ 2, 0 }), 234, "foo" },
};

void test(void) {
  int i;
  printf("%s\n", thing[1].name);
  for(i=0; i<thing[1].sizeof_a; i++)
    printf("%d, ", thing[1].a[i] );
}
```

Comment: This is quite good, but the initialization is a mess. I prefer to define an uninitialized struct, and initialize in a function call: `void init_obj(struct obj *obj, unsigned int num_a, const int *a, unsigned int num_b, const int *b, int c, const char *name);` which would be called multiple times during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version combining cnicutar, ouah, and unwind's various contributions. I'm not sure whether the extra verbosity is a good or bad thing.

```
struct object
{
  int *a;
  int sizeof_a;
  int *b;
  int sizeof_b;
  int c;
  const char *name;
};

struct object thing[] = {
  { .a=(int[]){ 4, 3, 2 }, .sizeof_a=sizeof((int[]){ 4, 3, 2 }), .b=(int[]){ 2, 0, 1 }, .sizeof_b=sizeof((int[]){ 2, 0, 1 }), .c=1234, .name="arfle" },
  { .a=(int[]){ 1, 2 }, .sizeof_a=sizeof((int[]){ 1,2 }), .b=(int[]){ 2, 0 }, .sizeof_b=sizeof((int[]){ 2, 0 }), .c=234, .name="foo" },
};

void test(void) {
  int i;
  printf("%s\n", thing[1].name);
  for(i=0; i<thing[1].sizeof_a; i++)
    printf("%d, ", thing[1].a[i] );
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: A good idea would be to make the size-fields have type `size_t` rather than `int`, in my opinion.